# RTRIM in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to trim some letters from my column in a table, but somehow not sure how the rtrim function is actually working in snowflake.
kindly help.

ex: I need to remove '+M+R' and '+M&R' from my column values.
here is the piece of code I tried

```
select rtrim('MEDIUM+M&R', '+M&R')
```

-----> MEDIU (the actual OUTPUT), but I need MEDIUM to be the final output

```
select rtrim('MEDIUM+M+R', '+M&R')
```

-----> MEDIU (the actual OUTPUT as above), but I need MEDIUM to be the final output

How it is trimming the letters?

Comment: 'M' is in you character search on right , so it is trimming off all M's on right side.You can go with  replace('MEDIUM+M&R', '+M&R')  it works well.

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for the help.
But I might have any one of them in the word, i.e. either +M+R or +M&R, so need to cut down these in a single condition!

Answer (score 2):

I think RTRIM is for specific chars,whitespaces etc. so it's probably not what you need in your case.

I would suggest using regexp_replace and replace it with '' -> nothing.

In your example regexp_replace('MEDIUM+M&R','\\+.*','') should return just MEDIUM. PS. double slash before + so it takes it as a part of string.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is always the first `+` you could do `split_part(column, '+', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

More to Jakub's answer

[RTRIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rtrim.html) (and thus [TRIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim.html)/[LTRIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ltrim.html)) take all the values that are in the remove set in any order while they still exist.

```
SELECT
    column1,
    rtrim(column1, '+M&R') as trim1,
    rtrim(column1, '+&RM') as trim2,
    regexp_replace(column1, '\\+M[&+]R','') as clean 
FROM VALUES
    /* what we want altered */
    ('MEDIUM+M&R'),
    ('MEDIUM+M+R'),
    /* things we don't want altered */
    ('MEDIUM+M++R'),
    ('MEDIUM++M&R'),
    ('AAMMMM+M+R'),
    ('AAMM')
```

Gives these results:

| COLUMN1 | TRIM1 | TRIM2 | CLEAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MEDIUM+M&R | MEDIU | MEDIU | MEDIUM |
| MEDIUM+M+R | MEDIU | MEDIU | MEDIUM |
| MEDIUM+M++R | MEDIU | MEDIU | MEDIUM+M++R |
| MEDIUM++M&R | MEDIU | MEDIU | MEDIUM+ |
| AAMMMM+M+R | AA | AA | AAMMMM |
| AAMM | AA | AA | AAMM |

This shows boths the "just keep taking while matching" nature of the TRIM functions, and how the regexp matches "that is correctly constrained" matches just what you want.

The regex used here would normally be `'\+M[&+]R'` but given it is parsed by the SQL parser the `\` needs to be escaped `\\` but we are saying match `+` then match `M` then match `&` OR `+` then match `R`

Comment: Hy Simeon, thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation, So what I understood from the trim is it will cut down whatever char we mentioned in the argument from the word.
If it is rtrim it'll cut all the trailing char irrespective of the orders, right?
So if I give select rtrim('MEDIUM+M+R', '+') 
, I thought it will cut all the char in the word starting from + , but it doesn’t seem to work in that way!
Where am I going wrong in understanding this ??

Comment: The list of tokens trimmed tokens is a collection to be remove until the first non match is found. It is not a fixed string like it appears. You possibly want ENDSWITH to match. But then regular expression are more useful if you have more than one toen to match

Comment: The expression which you have mentioned is perfectly working for me, thanks guys